# java complicated string parsing

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I need the most efficient way to parse the following string and extract the **imgurl** from it using java.

```
{ms:"images,5160.1",
turl:"http://ts1.mm.bing.net/th?id=I4693880201938488&pid=1.1",
height:"178",width:"300",
imgurl:"http://www.attackingsoccer.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/World-Cup-2012-Draw.jpg",
offset:"0",t:"World Cup 2014 Qualification – Europe Draw World Cup 2012 Draw ...",
w:"719",h:"427",ff:"jpeg",
fs:"52",durl:"www.attackingsoccer.com/2011/07/world-cup-2012-qualification-europe...",
surl:"http://www.attackingsoccer.com/2011/07/world-cup-2012-qualification-europe-draw/world-cup-2012-draw/",
mid:"D9E91A0BA6F9E4C65C82452E2A5604BAC8744F1B",k:"6",ns:"API.images"}"
```

For the above string the output should be :

`http://www.attackingsoccer.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/World-Cup-2012-Draw.jpg`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried splitting the string and then extracting the imgurl. However the problem is that I have 50+ such strings and splitting all of them wastes a lot of resources. Thats why I need something more efficient.

Comment: @Sid, your string data look like a [JSON](http://json.org) string, so, you can choose some JSON library to extract `imgurl` or other variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it's JSON message. 
You can convert this into POJO using e.g. GSON.

Answer (score 1):

This is in [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format. Find a parser that handles JSON data and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = YOUR STRING;
String startStr = "imgurl:¥"";
String endStr = ".jpg";

String value = str.subString(str.indexOf(startStr) + startStr.length , str.indexOf(endStr) + endStr.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `Pattern` and a `Matcher`:

```
String string = "something....,imgurl=\"blabla\",somethinother";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(",imgurl=\"[^\"]*\",");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
m.find();
String result = m.group().subSequence(1, m.group().length() - 1).toString();
```

This will work even if there are other places in the string where the text "imgurl:" or ".jpg" appears.